# How to get value counts for an array using np.unique in numba?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I've got a pandas dataframe, for which I need to calculate `GUID`s for `score` values above `threshold` grouped by `dataset` for thousand times using function `func42`. Because speed is very important for our team, I'm trying to compile a numba function. A sample code looks as follows:

```
threshold = 50    
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({"score": [73.5, 82.0, 90, 50, 63.9, 70],
                 "GUID": [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5],
                 "Dataset": [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1]})

def func42(df_1, threshold):

    df_1 = df_1[df_1[:, 0]>=threshold]
    rez_series = [len(np.unique(df_1[df_1[:, 2].astype("int")==dataset][:, 1].astype("int"), return_counts=True)[1]) for dataset in [1, 2, 3]]
    rez_series[2] = np.unique(df_1[:, 2], return_counts=True)[1][2]
    
    return rez_series
```

For this particular case, the output would be

```
func42(df_1.to_numpy(), 50)
```

> [2, 2, 1]

However, if I initialize it with `@njit`, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypingError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-344-5bfba31c5943> in <module>
     12 
     13     return rez_series
---> 14 func42(df_1.to_numpy(), 50)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py in _compile_for_args(self, *args, **kws)
    466                 e.patch_message(msg)
    467 
--> 468             error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
    469         except errors.UnsupportedError as e:
    470             # Something unsupported is present in the user code, add help info

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py in error_rewrite(e, issue_type)
    407                 raise e
    408             else:
--> 409                 raise e.with_traceback(None)
    410 
    411         argtypes = []

TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<function unique at 0x7fd1e4057c10>) found for signature:
 
 >>> unique(array(int64, 1d, C), return_counts=Literal[bool](True))
 
There are 2 candidate implementations:
      - Of which 2 did not match due to:
      Overload in function 'np_unique': File: numba/np/arrayobj.py: Line 2088.
        With argument(s): '(array(int64, 1d, C), return_counts=bool)':
       Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
         TypingError: got an unexpected keyword argument 'return_counts'
  raised from /home/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numba/core/typing/templates.py:791

During: resolving callee type: Function(<function unique at 0x7fd1e4057c10>)
During: typing of call at <ipython-input-344-5bfba31c5943> (10)


File "<ipython-input-344-5bfba31c5943>", line 10:
def func42(df_1, threshold):
    <source elided>
    df_1 = df_1[df_1[:, 0]>=threshold]
    rez_series = [len(np.unique(df_1[df_1[:, 2].astype("int")==dataset][:, 1].astype("int"), return_counts=True)[1]) for dataset in [1, 2, 3]] #'Control','Manipulated','CleanIds'
```

I can't understand where the error comes from, because np.unique is [supported](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/numpysupported.html) by numba, while `return_counts=True` keyword is necessary for value counts. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: What does the `numba` say?  **numpy.unique() (only the first argument)**

Comment: Thanks for a swift reply! Do you think there is any workaround to calculate values without using np.unique()?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html does probably what you need and is often faster than numpys version.

Comment: Alternatively, you can do a sort (like np.unique does), then a diff to find the values that are changing, then a `np.where` to locate the position of the changing values and `np.diff` to find the number of equal elements. The result of `np.where` give you the index of unique values. Doing that with loops in Numba is certainly a bit more efficient. That being said a sort is not great in term of performance and other implementation using hash-tables can be faster regarding the input (when the number of unique item is huge, this can be actually slower)

Comment: Thanks Jerome for your input! It's been some time since my question, but I managed to find a workaround using Python sets.

`rez_series = [len(set(df_1[df_1[:, 2].astype(np.int64)==dataset][:, 1].astype(np.int64))) for dataset in [1, 2, 3]]`

It allowed the function to keep the time efficiency in numba environment without using numpy functions to get value counts.